# Tengo un problema con un Script para Unity (error CS0116)

Tags: c#, script, unity3d

He estado tratando de crear un código para que el jugador de mi juego muera al caer desde determinada altura. Pero me sale siempre el siguiente error: **Assets\Scripts\cae.cs(6,13): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods**

Dejo el código para ver si alguien puede darme una mano:

`````
using System.Collections;
namespace x 
{
public float TiempoEnElAire;
public int ValorCaida; //Valor tope.
public bool EstaEnElAire;
public class cae  : MonoBehaviour 
{

public float TiempoEnElAire;
public int ValorCaida; //Valor tope.
public bool EstaEnElAire;


public void Update ()
{
if (EstaEnElAire == true)
{
TiempoEnElAire = 2 * Time.deltaTime; // Va haciendo un conteo multiplicado x2. Podes cambiar el numero para que vaya mas rapido.
} else 
{
 TiempoEnElAire = 0; // El valor vuelve a 0 sin deltaTime. ya que EstaEnElAire es FALSE.
}
}

public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Suelo") //Agregar tag al Suelo.
{
 if (EstaEnElAire == true)
 {
  if (TiempoEnElAire >= ValorCaida) //Si TiempoEnElAire es mayor o igual a ValorCaida. se ejecuta la acción.
   {
     Destroy(gameObject);
      //Aca dentro rellenas lo que queres.
   }
   EstaEnElAire = false;
 } else if (collision.gameObject.tag != "Suelo")
 {
 EstaEnElAire = true;
 }
}
}
}
}````
`````

Answer (score 0):

No puedes declarar las variables: `TiempoEnElAire`, `ValorCaida`, y `EstaEnElAire`, fuera de una clase.

Borra esas variables de las línes 4, 5 y 6. Con eso creo que es suficiente, porque ya las tienes definidas otra vez dentro de la clase.

Comment: Gracias! Voy a borrar esas líneas a ver que sucede....

Comment: No me funciona tampoco sin esas lineas....